# Parallel Processing using Multi Threading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am creating a Web App in which, I have to upload files by splitting them using parallel processing and multi threading and while downloading I have to combine them back to a single file using multi threading and parallel processing.
I want to combine split files into a single. But its not working as I expected to work.
The number of threads created is equal to the number of parts the file have been split.
And the threads should run parallelly and should run only once. But the threads are called several times. Help me fix the code.

**UploadServlet.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.Part;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;


public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 100L;
    public static String fileName;
    public static long size;
    public static int noOfParts;
    public static String type;
    public static byte[] b;
    private static final String INSERT_USERS_SQL = "INSERT INTO uploadlist" +
            " (filename, filesize, noofparts) VALUES " +
            "(?, ?, ?);";
    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Part file = request.getPart("file");
        fileName=file.getSubmittedFileName();
        type=file.getContentType();
        PrintWriter writer=response.getWriter();
        file.write(fileName);
        String n = request.getParameter("parts");
        size = file.getSize();
        Integer temp1 = Integer.parseInt(n);
        noOfParts = temp1.intValue();
        set();
        writer.println("File Uploaded Successfully");
        file.delete();
    }




public static void set()
{
    Split.split(fileName,size,noOfParts);
      try {
         Connection c = DataBaseConnection.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = c.prepareStatement(INSERT_USERS_SQL);
         preparedStatement.setString(1, fileName);
         preparedStatement.setLong(2, size);
         preparedStatement.setInt(3, noOfParts);
         System.out.println(preparedStatement);
         preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
      } catch (Exception e) 
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
}
```

From UploadServlet Split.split() is called to split the files into number of parts.

**Split.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Split implements Runnable
{
    int i;
    long size;
    int noOfParts;
    String fileName;
    Split()
    {
        fileName="";
    }
    Split(String fileName, int i, long size, int noOfParts)
    {
        this.fileName=fileName;
        this.i=i;
        this.size=size;
        this.noOfParts=noOfParts;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile("D:\\temp\\"+fileName,"r");
            int bytesPerSplit = (int)(size/noOfParts);
            int remainingBytes = (int)(size % noOfParts);
            byte[] b;
            if(i!=noOfParts-1)
            {
                b = new byte[bytesPerSplit];
            }
            else
            {
                b = new byte[bytesPerSplit+remainingBytes];
            }
            in.seek((long)i*bytesPerSplit);
            in.read(b);
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\Upload\\"+fileName+i+".bin"));
            for(byte temp : b)  
                out.write(temp);
            out.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void split(String fileName, long size, int noOfParts)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<noOfParts; i++)
        {
            Split obj = new Split(fileName,i,size,noOfParts);
            Thread t = new Thread(obj);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

In this program, I split the files according to number of parts. And I want to combine them back using Parallel Processing and Multi Threading.

**DownloadServlet.java**\

```
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import org.postgresql.Driver;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Arrays;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {
            String name = new String(request.getParameter("fileName"));
            int noOfParts = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("parts"));
            int size = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("size"));
            File downloadFile = new File("D:\\Download\\"+name);
            Combine.combine(name,noOfParts,size);
            int length = (int)downloadFile.length();
            String completeFile=name;
            ServletContext context=getServletContext();
            String mimeType = context.getMimeType(completeFile);
            if (mimeType == null) 
            {        
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            response.setContentLength((int)length);
            String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
            String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", completeFile);
            response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
            OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(downloadFile));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)length];
            while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1))
            {
                outStream.write(buffer,0,length);
            }
            if ((length = in.read(buffer))== -1) {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte)0);
            in.close();
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
        }
}
```

From DownloadServlet, Combine.combine() is called to combine the split parts into a single file.

**Combine.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Combine implements Runnable
{
    String name;
    int size;
    int noOfParts;
    int i;
    public static String root = "D:\\Upload\\";
    Combine(String name,int noOfParts,int size, int i)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.noOfParts=noOfParts;
        this.size=size;
        this.i=i;
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {   
            System.out.println(i);
            RandomAccessFile out = new RandomAccessFile("D:\\Download\\"+name,"rw");
            int bytesPerSplit = size/noOfParts;
            int remainingBytes = size%noOfParts;
            String temp=name+i+".bin";
            RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(root+temp,"r");
            long l=file.length();
            byte[] b = new byte[(int)l];
            file.read(b);
            out.seek(i*bytesPerSplit);
            out.write(b);
            file.close();
            out.close();
        }
        catch(IOException  e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void combine(String name, int noOfParts, int size)
    {   
        for(int i=0; i<noOfParts; i++)
        {
            Combine obj = new Combine(name,noOfParts,size,i);
            Thread t = new Thread(obj,"Thread"+i);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

[I have attached the image in which the numbers represent the part of the file being read and combined using threads.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2foJ.png)
The output shows that the threads keeping on executing again and again.
I don't know where is the error or any logical mistake in my program.
Help me solve this problem.

Comment: 1) Please post the relevant code of how those classes are actually used. The way it is now, it should run as expected. 2) Use try-resource instead of closing manually 3) You should not read from a drive in parallel from multiple sources. This may drastically slow down I/O input on larger files. With hard drive I/O, multiples threads will not speed anything up, nor make it faster, but will rather slow it down essentially on file sizes that exceed OS caching optimization. 4) Use keywords like private (visibility) and final (mutability) on your member variables so you can rely on their state.

Comment: Please share the code where split() and combine() methods are called from.

Comment: Added the programs in which they are called from.

Comment: I tried using Try with resources but now the page keeps on loading, and the file is not being downloaded. And I think the problem is the Output stream is not yet closed. @JayC667 https://imgur.com/kAB3kjw

Comment: 1) Sorry to ask this obvious question: has your code even worked with only 1 Thread? Basic up- and download? 2) Have you checked that your Servlets get only called once? 3) Produce more meaningful output than just printing a number. Explain in the output what that numer is. For example "Uloading file xyz with 12345 bytes in z parts".

Comment: Also, make sure you're NOT using the `static` keyword as a class variable of a servlet. This will have very very counter-intuitive effects (unless you really know what `static`does), and in your case make things really messed up if `UploadServlet` runs multiple times in parallel.

Comment: Yeah it worked well with a single thread and It works fine too if I add a join() method with the thread. @JayC667. And the servlets are being called only once.

Comment: Now for smaller files, it works fine but for larger files, it gets redirected to a page, where it tells an error that " The site can't be reached ". https://imgur.com/LYIuNJK and after several incomplete downloads, the final file gets downloaded. https://imgur.com/Ymnqoop